# Add entity declaration in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

How to add entity declaration in DOCTYPE using XSL 2.0.

```
<!DOCTYPE article
  PUBLIC "-//ES//DTD version 9.5.0//EN//XML" "XXX.dtd" 
[<!ENTITY img1 SYSTEM "img1" NDATA IMAGE>
<!ENTITY  img2 SYSTEM "img2" NDATA IMAGE>
]>
```

I try this code

```
<xsl:output doctype-public="-//ES//DTD version 9.5.0//EN//XML"  doctype-system="XXX.dtd"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commercial editions of Saxon 9 or 10 have support for that with extension instructions http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/instructions/doctype.html. Otherwise you would have to try to output such stuff with text node and using `disable-output-escaping="yes"`.